# Questions about Stein's Real Analysis Chapter 3 Exercise 3

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve the following problem in Stein's Real Analysis (exercise 3 Chapter 3)

[image]

and here is the partial proof that I found difficult to understand.

[image]

As far as I understand, the proof says $E \cap (-E)$ has positive measure, so $E$ has a sequence $\{x_n\}$ and the proof ends.

What I'm uncertain about is how the fact that a set has a positive measure guarantees the existence of a sequence in the set? Also, the exercise asks us to show the existence of a sequence that converges to $0$. But it seems the proof above doesn't prove it.

Any comments about how the proof makes sense would be appreciated. Also, If there is a better idea about this exercise, that would also be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does this "proof" come from? (not from Stein's book, I guess)

Comment: Of course it's not from Stein's textbook. I just received it from my friend, so I 'm not sure the exact source of this file either lol. Let me check your reply and add comments later, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Every countable set has Lebesgue measure $0.$ Hence a set of positive measure is (uncountably) infinite.
2. I think the solution is badly written. For each $n\in\Bbb N,$ $x_n$ must be chosen not in $E\cap(-E)$ but in $E_n\cap(-E_n),$ where $E_n=E\cap B_{1/n}(0)$ (for $1/n\le r_0$). This set $E_n\cap(-E_n)$ has positive measure (like $E\cap(-E)$) hence (by the previous point) it is non empty.